# Using Pyb-Library in WiPy

Tags: micropython

How do I use the pyb-library in WiPy? The documentation is incomplete. `import pyb`  doesn't work. Also not `from pyb import delay` or something. Also machine hasn't delay in it. How do I use following code?

https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/pyboard/library/pyb.html#pyb.delay

Comment: I think you would do better if you explained the exact thing you're trying to do (with the code you've tried) and not focus so much on the specific library. The SO community can point you to the right library if that's not it.

Answer (score 2):

easiest way to put a delay in micropython is

```
import time
time.sleep(Nseconds)
time.sleep_ms(N_milliseconds)
```

FYI:

`pyb` library is a module specific for pyboard, will not work in WiPy or ESP32 default micropython firmware. Basically the firmware for pyboard has a module called pyb along with other micropython standard modules. you could always add different modules and build a custom firmware and flash your WiPy.